# SAP Cloud SDK CI/CD Pipeline: Usage with non S\4 Services

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am using SAP Cloud SDK (Java flavour) to create an extension application of SuccessFactors.
I sadly discovered that the Jenkins pipeline does not allow me to use any other service than the ones listed here: [SCN Blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/22/quality-checks/) (scroll to the Appendix).

This does not make so much sense to me, as now the SDK can be used - and it is sponsored to be used by SAP - also with SaaS in its ecosystem, SuccessFactors being one of them.

Any hint? Can this check be somehow "bypassed"?

Thanks,
Roberto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the blog post is quite old, have you verified your assumption that it does not work with SuccessFactors API?

Nonetheless, we recently introduced a configuration option which allows you to disable certain checks, cf https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md#s4sdkqualitychecks

`checkServices` is what you would want to disable in your scenario.

Comment: True, it is old, but also the official documentation of Project Piper mentions that only official API Business Hub apis are supported. In a real world scenario (like mine) I am connecting directly to a SuccessFactors tenant API (which is, indeed, official).

Nevertheless, I found out that both the parameter you mentioned and parameter customODataServices can be customized to achieve the goal. Simply add the SuccessFactors API name into the customODataService array and it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Florian in the comment and following the Project Piper documentation, parameters "checkServices" and "customODataServices" can be used to customize the behavior of the pipeline when running upon a non-Business Hub API.

"checkServices: false" will completely deactivated the check, whereas "customODataServices: [ yourApiName ]" will skip the check just for the specified services.